# Could not import django.contrib.syndication.views.feed. View does not exist in module django.contrib.syndication.views. using django and rss

Tags: django, python-2.7, rss

I'm trying to get RSS to work with django

I have a social bookmarking app.

when I try to access the rss page at localhost:8000/feeds/recent/

I get the following error:

```
Could not import django.contrib.syndication.views.feed. View does not exist in module django.contrib.syndication.views.
```

I am using python 2.7.3 and django 1.5.1

I am only going to show the code that I think is relevant.

I have the following code in feeds.py

```
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed
from bookmarks.models import Bookmark

class RecentBookmarks(Feed):
    title = 'Django Bookmarks | Recent Bookmarks'
    link = '/feeds/recent/'
    description = 'Recent bookmarks posted to Django Bookmarks'
    def items(self):
        return  Bookmark.objects.order_by('id')[:10]
```

The urls.py has the following code I have left out the urls that are not relevant.

```
import os.path
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from bookmarks.views import *
from bookmarks.feeds import *
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from bookmarks.models import Link, Bookmark, Tag, SharedBookmark

site_media = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'site_media'
)

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

admin.site.register(Link)
class BookmarkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'link', 'user')
    list_filter = ('user',)
    ordering = ('title',)
    search_fields = ('title',)
admin.site.register(Bookmark, BookmarkAdmin)
admin.site.register(Tag)
admin.site.register(SharedBookmark)

feeds = {
    'recent': RecentBookmarks
}


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Feeds
    (r'^feeds/(?P<url>.*)/$', 'django.contrib.syndication.views.feed', 
                            {'feed_dict': feeds }),
)
```

The models.py looks like the following:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Link(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
    return self.url


class Bookmark(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    link = models.ForeignKey(Link)
    def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.user.username, self.link.url)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.link.url
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book I have been learning Django from is quite old.

I discovered from looking at the Django Documentation that the url pattern that's required can now go straight to RecentBookmarks.

I first looked [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/contrib/syndication/)

and compared it with [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/syndication/)

From this comparison I discovered that what I need to do is change the url pattern to the following.

```
(r'^feeds/(?P<url>.*)/$', RecentBookmarks()),
```

I also found that in RSS does not work with google chrome browser unless I installed the [RSS Subscription extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rss-subscription-extensio/nlbjncdgjeocebhnmkbbbdekmmmcbfjd?hl=en)

After making these changes it now works correctly.